# Default sms app chooser is not displaying

Tags: java, android, sms, default, native-android

I am working on an Sms app, I want my app to display the below chooser, so that the user can select my app as default
[image]

here is my manifest code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <!-- <service android:name=".BackgroundService" />-->

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service
            android:name=".BackgroundService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

and here is my mainActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!isDefaultSmsApp(this))
            setDefaultSmsApp();
    }

    private void setDefaultSmsApp() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Setting default....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent =
                new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
        intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
                getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public boolean isDefaultSmsApp(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return context.getPackageName().equals(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context));
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void requestSmsPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed to send messages")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialogInterface, i) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, ACCESS_SMS_CODE))
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, ACCESS_SMS_CODE);
        }

    }
```

What am i missing ?

I have also tried using intent.createChooser but it was not working, as you can see i have registered all the necessary registers in my manifest,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I was able to show the dialog here is the updated code for my Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_default_sms);

    if (!isDefaultSmsApp(this))
        setDefaultSmsApp();
}


private void setDefaultSmsApp() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        //String mypackagename = getPackageName();
        if(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this)!=null){
            if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(getPackageName())){
                openMainActivity();
            }else{
                Intent setSmsAppIntent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                setSmsAppIntent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,getPackageName());
                startActivityForResult(setSmsAppIntent, 1);
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No default Sms App found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
    else{
        RoleManager rolemanager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(RoleManager.class);
        if (rolemanager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)){
            if (rolemanager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)){
                openMainActivity();
            }
            else{
                Intent roleRequestIntent = rolemanager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
                startActivityForResult(roleRequestIntent,REQUEST_SET_DEFAULT_SMS_APP);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone!